# unable to get react app started when starting node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm following a tutorial on react, and the final step is to start node, but when I do "npm start" as indicated by [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_environment_setup.htm). I get this error.

here's the error cmd line is giving me on starting node "npm start"

```
C:\Users\George\Desktop\reactapp>npm start
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.15063
npm ERR! argv "C:\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.11.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! file C:\Users\George\Desktop\reactapp\package.json
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE

npm ERR! Failed to parse json
npm ERR! Unexpected token '"' at 11:3
npm ERR!   "keywords": [
npm ERR!   ^
npm ERR! File: C:\Users\George\Desktop\reactapp\package.json
npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! This is not a bug in npm.
npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\George\Desktop\reactapp\npm-debug.log
```

and finally here's my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "reactapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "test react application",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
      "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
      "start": "node server.js"
    }
}
  "keywords": [
    "test",
    "react",
    "application"
  ],
  "author": "George Louis",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "webpack": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing comma between `}` and `"keywoards"`, Also you have sufficient `}`.

Your JSON should look like

```
  {
    "name": "reactapp",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "test react application",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "start": "node server.js"
    },
    "keywords": [
        "test",
        "react",
        "application"
    ],
    "author": "George Louis",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "webpack": "^3.0.0"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read the trace, npm is telling you the answer

```
npm ERR! Unexpected token '"' at 11:3
npm ERR!   "keywords": [
npm ERR!   ^
npm ERR! File: C:\Users\George\Desktop\reactapp\package.json
```

It tells you whats' wrong (the comma), at which line (11) and which row (3) of which file (`C:\Users\George\Desktop\reactapp\package.json`).

So, you are missing a comma:

```
      "start": "node server.js"
    }
  },
  "keywords": [
    "test",
    "react",
    "application"
  ],
```

Notice the comma before "keywords", that is missing in your JSON, hence it is invalid.

Comment: did you try putting the comma.. I just did and it moved the error to the newly added comma "Failed to parse json
npm ERR! Unexpected token ',' at 10:2
npm ERR! },
npm ERR!  ^ "

Comment: now I"m getting a bunch of error complaining about the server update... any suggestions?.  
npm ERR! node v6.11.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! reactapp@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! Failed at the reactapp@1.0.0 start script 'node server.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the reactapp package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system: